# Brexit means Frexit

Tags: discussion, moderators

I feel like I'm not getting as much out of moderating this site as I'm putting in. I'm also worried about the recent influx of moderators to the site who don't share my values. I think I'd probably be better off moderating on my own for a bit.

[Jokes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfVsfOSbJY0) aside, I'm very sad to be [announcing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qevJE.jpg) that I'm stepping down as a mod. It's just that recent changes at work mean I have a lot less time, to the extent that I haven't really participated in any moderating at all for the last couple of months, and I don't see that situation changing.

Moderating this site has been a real privilege, and the support of my fellow moderators and the Community Management team has been superb throughout.

Comment: Will you still be able to do chat stuff?

Comment: I will still be able to chat, yes.

Comment: It's a bummer to see you go, but we thank you for your hard work and dedication!

Comment: You don't need a diamond next to your name to show how awesome you are <3 Good luck with your changes in your life, hope all goes well.

Comment: If we just delay forever on Article Friday, can Frexit be postponed indefinitely?

Comment: But how can you be a diamond porkchop without a diamond?

Comment: @Dragonrage :-(

Comment: Thanks for everything old chap, hopefully we'll still see you around! Chat will be sad and empty without your Brexit memes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your dedication to the site, the effort you have put in means a great deal to all of us. We hope to continue to see you around, and may you be sucessful in whatever you go on to do in the future!

Comment: If I upvote this, does it mean "Yay!! Frexit"? Or should I downvote this, so it means Frexit :-( Its a bummer to see you go. Thanks for your hard work.

Comment: Relevant: [How do I leave the dance floor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/218607/how-do-i-leave-the-dance-floor)

Comment: I don't understand the title. Is that some inside joke?

Comment: @TomášZato [Brexit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit) is the UK leaving the EU.  Frexit would be *fr*edley leaving the mod team.

Comment: @Batophobia Ah... I thought he means Frexit as the France leaving the EU.

Comment: Don't forget to sign up for moderator retirement benefits.  Not because there are any, but because...  I actually don't know where I'm going with this joke.  Welcome to the club, at any rate :D

Comment: @agent86 I thought the usual procedure was to leave the site forever?

Answer (score 31):

I know I speak for the entire mod team when I say it's been an honour serving alongside you.

Answer (score 23):

Well, I can talk and thank about everything from the warning (oh I didn't forget it, heh) to the great help you provided to this community (and apologize for all the times I confused you with badp)...

But instead, I'll try and get my feelings out with a meme:

[image: Never mind Brexit, who won Frexit]

Comment: The answer is: Nobody won in Frexit :< (maybe his employer?)

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for your work and support fredley. With the Arqade being (by far) the SE site I've spent the most time on, I can appreciate the effort it takes to be a moderator.

Comment: Other SE sites exist? in all seriousness though, I agree with everything said here.